# Understanding some equality in a proof of the Main Theorem of Kummer Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, kummer-theory

I do not understand the underlined equality in the following context:

[image]

As I can see, one tried to apply the map $B$ on $F[B(E)^{1/n}]$ and $F$. I can see that the equality makes sense if we know that $B$ is a bijection. However, I think this is what we are trying to show in this theorem, so this argument does not work.

Could you please help explaining to me this equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E/F$ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. On page $72$ of [Fields and Galois Theory](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FT.pdf), Milne shows that $F^{\times}\cap E^{\times n}/F^{\times n}$ is isomorphic to ${\rm Hom}(G,\mu_n)$ and if $G$ is abelian of exponent $n$, $$|{\rm Hom}(G,\mu_n)|=(G:1)=[E:F].$$
Therefore if $G$ is abelian of exponent $n$,
$$[E:F]=(F^{\times}\cap E^{\times n}:F^{\times n})=(B(E):F^{\times n}),$$
where $B(E)=F^{\times}\cap E^{\times n}$.

In your case, $F[B(E)^{1/n}]$ is a finite abelian extension of exponent $n$ (actually, Milne proves this in the next paragraph) and the equality follows.